# How to add a new column in the dataframe respecting a python rule?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
      import numpy as np
      import pandas as pd

      df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Station', 'Station', 'Sensor', 'Sensor', 
                                  'Sensor', 'Sensor', 'Station', 'Station'], 
                        'id': [10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13]})

      print(df)
```

Output:

```
               Name     id
             Station    10
             Station    10
             Sensor     11
             Sensor     11
             Sensor     12
             Sensor     12
             Station    13
             Station    13
```

In addition to this dataframe, I also have an array with some ids:

```
      array_id = np.array([10, 11])
```

I would like to create a new column in the dataframe, called a class, and assign the labels 'class1' and 'class2'. For ids belonging to 'array_id' it would receive 'class1' and for ids not belonging to 'array_id' it would receive 'class2'. I tried to do this as per the following code:

```
       # Create a new column with NaN
       df['class'] = np.NaN

      for i in range(0, len(df)):
          for j in range(0, len(array_id)):          
    
             if(array_id[j] == df['id'].iloc[i]):  
                  df['class'].iloc[i] = 'class1'
             else:
                  df['class'].iloc[i] = 'class2'
```

The (wrong) output is:

```
     print(df)

       Name     id  class  
      Station   10  NaN
      Station   10  NaN
      Sensor    11  NaN
      Sensor    11  NaN
      Sensor    12  NaN
      Sensor    12  NaN
      Station   13  NaN
      Station   13  NaN
```

I would like the output to be:

```
       Name     id  class  
      Station   10  class1
      Station   10  class1
      Sensor    11  class1
      Sensor    11  class1
      Sensor    12  class2
      Sensor    12  class2
      Station   13  class2
      Station   13  class2
```

Comment: `df['class'] = np.where(df['id'].isin(array_id), 'class1', 'class2')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang You can add "Use:" in front of it and make it answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use `pandas` without `numpy`, you can use `loc` and `fillna`:

```
df.loc[df.id.isin(array_id),'class'] = 'class1'
df['class'].fillna('class2',inplace=True)
```

---

```
      Name  id   class
0  Station  10  class1
1  Station  10  class1
2   Sensor  11  class1
3   Sensor  11  class1
4   Sensor  12  class2
5   Sensor  12  class2
6  Station  13  class2
7  Station  13  class2
```